# converting time stamp to minutes elapsed taking calendar start as reference in R

Tags: r, timestamp, rstudio

have some time stamp data

```
2016-03-01 21:02:56.440
```

can this be converted to number of minutes taking start of calendar as reference

```
1456846376.44
```

units is minutes
any leads will be appreciated

Comment: Do you need `as.numeric(as.POSIXct(str1))`  What do you mean by `start of calendar`

Comment: thanks i needed this only

Comment: which only you want?

Comment: i needed this only but in minutes so manipulated accordingly